# Enter an array of datasets into the dataset field of ChartJs

Tags: chart.js

Is there a way in which I can create an array of dataset objects and pass that straight into the construction of a chart, rather than manually passing in dataset objects like here:

This works:

```
 myChart[0] = new Chart(ctx, {
type: barbarblackbar,
data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [xdata, ydata]
    },
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
}
});
```

This doesn't:

```
var datData = { ydata, xdata };

myChart[0] = new Chart(ctx, {
type: barbarblackbar,
data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: datData
    },
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
}
});
```

I know this may be a simple fix but I have tried everything I can think of

Comment: It looks like you're passing an object in the second snippet. Chart.js charts only accept arrays I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd approach will work just fine if you change your definition of `datData` from an object to an array:

```
var datData = [ ydata, xdata ];

myChart[0] = new Chart(ctx, {
type: barbarblackbar,
data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: datData
    },
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
}
});
```